Can Weapon Property Runes apply to Athletics maneuvers?
Recent errata has clarified that if you use an athletics maneuver with a weapon, the weapon's traits, such as Agile, can apply. Do property runes apply as well?
For example, a Crushing rune says it applies its effects on a critical hit with the weapon, and mentions attacks, but does not say that this effect is only for strikes.

Weapons with this rune empower your strength, and attacks with these weapons leave your foe staggered. When you critically hit a target with this weapon, your target becomes clumsy 1 and enfeebled 1 until the end of your next turn.

If, for instance, my weapon has the Trip trait, and I critically Trip an opponent with it, can I apply my Crushing rune's effect?

Mostly No.
There are a handful of property runes which hypothetically could apply to Athletics maneuvers, such as if you critically succeeded on a trip against an enemy while using a Bloodthirsty weapon, and the 1d6 damage from the critical success reduced your target to 0 hp.
In the vast majority of cases, however, and in the given example, the Property Rune does not apply to Athletics maneuvers, because its effects trigger on a "Critical Hit".  A "Critical Hit" is a "Critical Success", but a "Critical Success" is only a "Critical Hit" for a Strike.
Because Trip is not a Strike, it cannot "Critically Hit", and therefore cannot trigger the Crushing property rune, or any other property rune which applies on a critical hit.

EDIT: Also, for further context, this issue was explicitly clarified in the remaster. The entry for Critical Hits previously mentioned attacks, which would support the use of property runes on athletics maneuvers. After the remaster, the Critical Hits section was changed to explicitly refer to strikes.
